# Streaming voice between Android Phones over UDP playback issues

Tags: android, multithreading, audiorecord, audiotrack

I am trying to stream voice between 2 android phones in real time. My idea is to use AudioRecord for recording and AudioTrack for playing. The packets seem to go fine but the playback sounds very spiky and a has a lot of noise. How can I solve it?

Here is my sender activity -

```
private static int BUFFER_SIZE = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(
        44100, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);

AudioRecord recorder = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC,
   44100, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, BUFFER_SIZE * 10);

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[8000]; 
            DatagramPacket packet; 
            recorder.startRecording();
            while(!stopClicked){
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(90); //Recording 90ms duration packets
                    int out = recorder.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
                    packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer, out, inetAddress, 4444);
                    clientSocket.send(packet);
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();}
            }
        }
    }).start();
```

On receiver side, I am using two threads - One for collecting the packets and other for playing the packets using AudioTrack
Here is my receiver activity -

```
AudioTrack myAudioTrack = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL, 44100, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO,
            AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, 16000,AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);
    myAudioTrack.play();
    playerThread = new Thread(m_packetCollector);
    playerThread.start();
    new receiveUDPTask().execute();
```

And the threads are -

```
Runnable m_packetCollector = new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
        Thread.currentThread().setPriority(Thread.MIN_PRIORITY);
        byte[] noiseData = null;
        while(true){
            if (!packetQueue.isEmpty()) {
                noiseData = packetQueue.remove();
                myAudioTrack.write(noiseData, 0, noiseData.length);
 }}}};


private class receiveUDPTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{
    byte[] buf = new byte[8000];
    DatagramPacket dp = new DatagramPacket(buf, 8000);
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        while(true){
            System.out.println("Listening for packets");
            try {
                serverSocket.receive(dp);
                packetQueue.add(buf);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
}}}}
```

Everything seems to be fine. I don't understand where the error is. Please help me locate it.

Comment: Use AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize() and AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize() instead of your own buffer sizes.

Comment: Were you able to solve this. I have a very similar implementation.

Comment: No. I did not do it later. @hadez30